# Adding simple tap recognition to iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, touch

I have just started trying to learn how to write apps for iPad. I have experience with C, C++ and Java, but am very new to Objective C ios in general.

I have a custom UIView that draws a number line to the screen and I have some working buttons that trigger methods in this view.

What I would like to do is have touching the drawn number line call a method in my UIView. More generally, any tap on the background should call this method with it screen coordinates so I can then decide if they touched he right place and what to do.

I've been searching for many hours now for info and am going in circles a bit. As far as I can see it is normal to add gesture recognition code to the ViewController instead of the UIView (I am having Xcode do as much as possible for me automatically, so only have a very basic understanding of these different parts).

The problem is that all the "brains" of the program are in the UIView (I want to move a drawn arrow to a new tapped location on the number line). But if I have a method in the ViewController responding to a touch event, I can't figure out how to call my UIView methods from within my controller.

Easiest would be a method directly in my UIView subclass that was called from the touch event.

All I have done so far is used Xcode to set up a single view application and created one UIView subclass (Called FracLine) which then draws the number line and an arrow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder) (which UIView inherits from), you will see the methods near the bottom pertaining to touch. Those methods all give you an NSSet of touches which contains UITouch objects. [UITouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has an instance method called locationInView: that will give you a CGPoint to see where it is touched.